# Pandas: How to index rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
stock_symbol    stock_date      stock_price_open     stock_price_high   
QRR             8/2/10  2.37    2.42                 2.29
QTM             5/2/10  2.38    2.5                  2.34
QXM             4/2/10  2.57    2.64                 2.39
```

I read a NYSE dataset:
`df = pandas.read_csv('NYSE.csv', index_col = 0, parse_dates=True)`

When I ran:
`df[['QRR','QTM','QXM']]`

I got this error:
`KeyError: "['QRR' 'QTM' 'QXM'] not in index"`

'QRR', 'QTM', 'QXM' are values of stock_symbol column. Could anyone please show me how to index them?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [11]: df.loc[['QRR','QTM','QXM']]
Out[11]:
                stock_date  stock_price_open  stock_price_high
stock_symbol
QRR           8/2/10  2.37              2.42              2.29
QTM           5/2/10  2.38              2.50              2.34
QXM           4/2/10  2.57              2.64              2.39
```

---

Without loc, `df[['QRR','QTM','QXM']]`, pandas is trying to select those columns (which don't exist, hence the "not in index" message):

```
In [21]: df[["stock_price_open", "stock_price_high"]]
Out[21]:
              stock_price_open  stock_price_high
stock_symbol
QRR                       2.42              2.29
QTM                       2.50              2.34
QXM                       2.64              2.39
```

check out the [selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) section of the docs.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I thought when I create a DataFrame from the .csv dataset with this code:
`df = pandas.read_csv('NYSE.csv', index_col = 0, parse_dates=True)`

The `index_col = 0` would set index for the first column (stock_symbol)

Comment: @KiemNguyen ah, yes it does precisely that! ok you just need to use loc :) updated the answer